# Memory Warning just in the beginning of the application

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am getting continous Memory Warnings just in the beginning of the application. What is the best way to find out where am I wrong? In the Leaks instrument, I cannot see anything wrong.

[image]

This is the screenshot from a generation.
[image]

Here I started to play a video. ImageIO_PNG_Data can be that? 
[image]

Comment: please, provide more information about what you are doing when your app launches. it would also be interesting to know whether used memory goes down after the launch phase.

Answer (score 1):

So you should use Allocations tool using "Heapshots"/"Generations" to look at what objects have been allocated and not released. (Not everything shows up as a "leak".) It could be that your app has strong reference cycles. Or it could be that your app is simply extravagant in its use of memory (e.g. maintaining arrays of images or the like). It's impossible for us to say on the basis of the information provided.

I'd suggest watching WWDC 2012 video [iOS App Performance: Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=242), which describes types of memory considerations and illustrates the use of Instruments to identify memory issues.